# Neo4j Cypher: true boolean is recognized as string

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher, node-neo4j

In my application, to change the visibility of a node, I defined a `is_full_show` parameter which takes a `true` or `false`. I have an `updateNodeEntity()` function to change the other parameter values when needed. Following is part of my Cypher query in `updateNodeEntity()` function:

```
"START n=node(" + nodeId + ") SET n.first_Name='" + neLabel + "', n.is_full_show=true, n.need_ne_update_approval=false";
```

When I run the query, I can see the parameter(s) changed successfully. However, the boolean `n.is_full_show=true` becomes a string `n.is_full_show="true"` and my node doesn't appear in my app. For more detailed description, following is the request payload from console:

```
ne_id:5306
ne_name:"Mike Mice"
ne_properties:"["email","address","first_Name","last_Name","membership","is_full_show","n.need_ne_update_approval"]"
ne_properties_val:"["mike@mikemail.com","123S Street","Mike","Mice","Silver",true,false]"
```

and the response:

```
"properties": {
    "Email": "mike@mikemail.com",
    "Address": "123S Street",
    "first_Name": "Mike",
    "Last_Name": "Mice",
    "Membership": "Silver",
    "is_full_show": "true",
    "n.need_ne_update_approval":"false"
}
```

I tried many options such as `return true` with a function, regexp, etc. But could not fix it. Any help/suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show us a minimal working example of JavaScript code with such behavior.

Comment: Top of my head, but have you tried writing it like this - 'true' - inside single quotes?